# How to use categoryId in Foursquare Venues search API

Tags: foursquare

I am getting unexpected results from API queries when including a categoryId parameter.

For instance, when using the following parameters to search for 'The Citizen Public House' in Boston, MA

```
ll: 42.3489027315987, -71.096134185791
query: citizen 
categoryId: 4bf58dd8d48988d116941735    <== 'bars'
```

The results wind up including venues from other categories, like 'banks'. Is there something wrong with the categoryId parameter? In the API documentation it is labeled 'experimental.' Am I using it improperly?

FYI: I am using the quimby gem to interface with the foursquare API via a rails app.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

If the place you were looking for is

> Citizen Public House & Oyster Bar

Then you were using the wrong categoryId :( 
The categories have an hierarchy, and search is done by it.

Specifically, `4bf58dd8d48988d116941735` is the bars category
That place is a Whisky Bar, category ID: `4bf58dd8d48988d122941735`

Why banks returned, not sure :) I am almost sure that when searching with a query, the foursquare engine forces results to match the query, regardless of other filters.

You should [download all categories](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) and see the categories tree to better understand which ID to use.
Note, you can look for the Nightlife category `4d4b7105d754a06376d81259`
which have all bars included in it, since you are looking with a query you should find what you are looking for (you can also try experimenting with `intent=match` or browse and a radius as well).

Comment: Category restricts and queries should work at the same time. We'll investigate to see if there's a bug in that behavior.

Comment: sorry, i picked the wrong categoryId for my example. I also ran the query with the nightlife categoryId and also the one above that in the tree, which I believe is food. In all cases my query returned banks and other spurious results.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I use the top level food categoryID: 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259, but I see results for venues in other categories.

Comment: I just experienced the same behavior today. I also used the top level food categoryId but there are non-food results. When I tried it with Foursquare's API Explorer, the query returned the expected results under the "Food" category. I also set the "intent" parameter to "browse" but there are no problems before.  But after removing the "intent" parameter, it is back to normal again.  And I also found a problem which is same with mine: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9307939/204575

Comment: Same here, a year+ later... seems the categoryId doesn't do much.

Comment: Same problem, in 2016... If you have no choice but using foursquare, it is better to use /venues/explore and a section filter.

Answer (score 3):

Super late, but i found that if you put the `categoryId` parameter directly after `...search?` and before your authentication and version parameters, it works.

eg. `search?categoryId=123&client_id=456&client_secret=789&v=20140828`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the categoryIDs at foursquare are the same. I just polled for an airport and let it give me its categoryID and then did the same for bars. They both had the same categoryID.

I found one different categoryID (4eb1bc533b7b2c5b1d4306cb Airport Lounge) and when using it as a filter it returned only results with this ID.