# categoryId ignored for intent=browse searches in foursquare venues/search

Tags: api, foursquare

As of a few days ago, foursquare venues/search with intent=browse seems to ignore categoryId. It definitely worked before that. If I change intent=checkin the category filtering is applied. Here's a sample query

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?radius=1405&ll=37.769587%2C-122.420139&limit=30&intent=browse&client_id=CLIENTID&v=20120216&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259

note I'm doing a userless query. Perhaps related to the recent changes to allow multiple categoryId's?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and the team is investigating a fix. Thanks for the report

Comment: This was fixed Saturday afternoon

Comment: Quick? 2 days (at least) for a major bug in one of the most popular consumer web APIs out there?  Add to that, the only information available on the status is buried here on SO in a 15 word answer with no helpful information. Nothing on the status blog, google group, etc. This is a horrible way to do developer relations.