# Getting valid data with the Foursquare API category?

Tags: api, foursquare

I want to search a result and sort it by `categoryId`.  I also want to use some categories.

So, I've sent a request with this parameter:

> `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=35.660853,139.688323&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4bf58dd8d48988d1a1941735,4bf58dd8d48988d116941735,4bf58dd8d48988d117941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d119941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d5941735,4bf58dd8d48988d121941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11c941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d4941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11d941735,4bf58dd8d48988d122941735,4bf58dd8d48988d123941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef931735&radius=1000&oauth_token=token&v=20120602`

But, the response data has a different `categoryID` than that of my request!

- My request category:

  > 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4bf58dd8d48988d1a1941735,4bf58dd8d48988d116941735,4bf58dd8d48988d117941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d118941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d119941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d5941735,4bf58dd8d48988d121941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11c941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1d4941735,4bf58dd8d48988d11d941735,4bf58dd8d48988d122941735,4bf58dd8d48988d123941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef931735
- ResponseCategory:

  > contains 4bf58dd8d48988d129951735(station) etc...

Why do you receive this data response?
How do I get the correct data response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug with foursquare API and category filtering. I have posted about this before and they said they are checking into it and in theory it should not happen (hence, a bug)

You can see a similar question here: [How to use categoryId in Foursquare Venues search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522201/how-to-use-categoryid-in-foursquare-venues-search-api/8522957#8522957)
and as you see more people experience the same problem.

In our system, after getting the results for search we filter it ourselves, so this is minor to us, the only thing annoying about this is that there is a chance it makes other legitimate venues drop out (as foursquare will return up to 50) - but we do not really know what the problem with the categoryid filtering at foursquare end, so this is a guess for the annoyance part :)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.<br/>
<br/>
I understand this phenomenon.<br/>
<br/>
Venue has same categories.<br/>
Example. <br/>
Tokyo Shibuya Station has station, food truck ... etc.<br/>
I requested Food Category.<br/>
So, Foursquare API returned Shibuya Station.<br/>
Because, Shibuya Station contains "food truck".<br/>
<br/>
I hope search the way to Primary Category only.<br/>
I saw API Docs. But, I have no way.<br/>
<br/>
Do you know this request the way?<br/>

Comment: No, do not think it is possible to search on primary only.
However, **it is possible** to process the search results and only show things with primary category relevant to what you need (search results contain a flag if the category is primary).
Take in mind that sometimes, according to my experience and the examples in the question I linked, you can get other venues, not related at all (like banks when you search for bars in that example) - but this hardly ever happen.