# FourSquare venue search return items from wrong categories?

Tags: foursquare

I'm using the FourSquare venue search, and specifying the categoryId to filter by category. But I keep getting items from other categories.

For example, when I specify the Food category, the results include private homes. When I specifying the Professional & Other Places category, the results include roads.

I've retrieved the FourSquare category hierachy. Here're the relevant items:

```
Professional & Other Places: 4d4b7105d754a06375d81259
Food: 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
Residence: 4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a
    Home (private): 4bf58dd8d48988d103941735
Travel & Transport: 4d4b7105d754a06379d81259
    Road: 4bf58dd8d48988d1f9931735
```

When I send the following request, searching within the Food (4d4b7105d754a06374d81259) category:

```
venues/search?query=nørrebrogade&intent=browse&ll=55.69434,12.54886&radius=10000&categoryId= 4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
```

Then the result include a private home (category 4bf58dd8d48988d103941735) as the first item:

```
id: "4be508d0910020a1ac98d214"
name: "Nørrebrogade"
contact: {}
location: {
    isFuzzed: true
    lat: 55.68978577050405
    lng: 12.550528230660262
    distance: 2748
    cc: "DK"
    state: ""
    country: "Denmark"
}
categories: [{
    id: "4bf58dd8d48988d103941735"
    name: "Home (private)"
    pluralName: "Homes (private)"
    shortName: "Home"
    icon: {
        prefix: "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/home_"
        suffix: ".png"
    }
    primary: true
}]
verified: false
stats: {
    checkinsCount: 140
    usersCount: 52
    tipCount: 0
}
specials: {
    count: 0
    items: []
}
hereNow: {
    count: 0
    groups: []
}
referralId: "v-1385461452"
```

I realize that specifying a category will also return items from sub-categories. But Food and 
Residence are different top level categories, so why is this result returned?

In the same way, using the categoryId 4d4b7105d754a06375d81259 (Professional & Other Places), returns an item from a different top level category Road (4bf58dd8d48988d1f9931735).

I'm using intent=browse.

I found this question [Getting valid data with the Foursquare API category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861396/getting-valid-data-with-the-foursquare-api-category), which sounds similar, but doesn't contain any solution, except manually filtering the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're seeing this because categoryId filtering also matches secondary categories. If you make a [venue details request](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4be508d0910020a1ac98d214) for that venue, you see that it has "Home (private)" set as its primary category (which is reflected in the search result), but you also see that somebody has categorized this as a Falafel and Middle Eastern Restaurant (whether or not this is valid is a question for our [community](https://foursquare.com/edit/)). The top-level Food category was matched on this subcategory.