# Foursquare venue search

Tags: ios, iphone, foursquare

In my iPhone app I want to search for nearby restaurants. With foursquare place API i get the json for nearby venues.

What is the url to get near by restaurants only? Currently I am getting all the venues.

I am using this url now:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&v=YYYYMMDD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same API. According to [this doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search), you can pass in `categoryId` parameter to specify that you only want restaurants.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522957/361247), you can download available categories with [this API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories) which will give you an array of categories. Make sure you only call that API endpoint once every session, and don't cache it more than a week.